# Get all parent hierarchy from a work Item via API Azure Boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I need to get all the parent hierarchy from a work item.

The parent of the parent of the parent.. find all the parent links.

There is a way to do it via API?

Thanks :)

Comment: See my answer, let me know whether that achieve your requirement. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

But you must use code to handle this situation. The below is a Python demo.

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

#get all the work items linked to a work item
def get_work_items_parents(Organization_Name, personal_access_token, wi_id):
    #get a connection to Azure DevOps
    organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+Organization_Name
    credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
    connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
    work_item_tracking_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
    work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(wi_id, expand="relations")
    #get the work item links
    for item in work_item.relations:
        #get parent and child work items
        if item.attributes['name'] == 'Parent':
            #get the work item id
            work_item_id = item.url.split('/')[-1]
            #get the work item
            linked_work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(work_item_id)

            #add the work item to the list
            work_items_parents.append(linked_work_item)
            #get the parents of the parent
            get_work_items_parents(Organization_Name, personal_access_token, work_item_id)
    return work_items_parents


personal_access_token = 'xxx'
Organization_Name = 'xxx'
workitem_id = 120
#create a list
work_items_parents = []

items = get_work_items_parents(Organization_Name, personal_access_token, workitem_id)

for item in items:
    print(item.fields['System.Title'])
```

I can successfully get all parents of workitem id '120':

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above is the API of Python SDK Demo, if you want to use REST API, I can also give you an idea.

Just call this REST API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/wit/workitems/<Workitem ID>?api-version=6.0&$expand=relations
```

You can call it again after getting the current parent:

[image]

Official document of the REST API:

[Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following PowerShell script: (In this sample, the work item `2434`is the last parent work item - top1 parent, `2435` is top2 parent ...)

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}", 
   [string]$project = "Artifacts",
   [string]$workitemid = "2527", #The specific child work item ID
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get all parent hierarchy from a specific work Item
cls
$parenturl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/workItems/$($workitemid)?"+"$"+"expand=relations&api-version=6.0"

$parentwi = @()
Do {
    $wiresults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $parenturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    $wirelations = $wiresults.relations | where{$_.rel -eq 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse'}
    $parentwi +=  $wiresults.id
    $wiurl = $wirelations.url
    #Print the parent work item link
    Write-Host $wiurl
    $parenturl = "$wiurl"+"?"+"$"+"expand=relations&api-version=6.0"
}
While($wiurl)

#Print the work items hierarchy Child -> Parent
Write-Host "########################################"
Write-Host "Work Items Hierarchy : Child -> Parent"
Write-Host "########################################"
$parentwi
```

[image]